# Saving and loading a class state from and to steam c++

Tags: c++, serialization, io, stream, binary

I'm trying to figure out how to save and load an objects state to a binary stream. For context, we currently have this working but only a 'save-to-file' implementation. However, we want the serialization done in-memory to better interact with some parallelization libraries. I'm hoping this will be quite simple but my current implementation doesn't do much - can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
class ForSerializationAsBinary {
public:
    ForSerializationAsBinary() = default;

    explicit ForSerializationAsBinary(int number)
            : number_(number) {}

    std::ostringstream toBinaryStream() {
        std::ostringstream out(std::ios::binary);
        out.write((char *) &number_, sizeof(int));
        return out;
    }

    static void fromBinaryStream(ForSerializationAsBinary &obj, std::ostringstream &os) {
        int n;
        std::istringstream is(std::ios::binary);
        is.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(os.rdbuf());
        is.read((char *) &n, sizeof(int));
        std::cout << "n: " << n << std::endl;
        obj.number_ = n;
    }

    int number_;
};

TEST(Serialisation, SimpleSerialization) {
    ForSerializationAsBinary serializationAsBinary(4);
    auto o = serializationAsBinary.toBinaryStream();
    ForSerializationAsBinary loaded;
    ForSerializationAsBinary::fromBinaryStream(loaded, o);
    std::cout << "loaded.number_: " << loaded.number_ << std::endl;

}
```

And the current output of the test

```
n: 0
loaded.number_: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer : just use a `std::stringstream` instead of the `o` or `i` versions:

```
class ForSerializationAsBinary {
public:
    ForSerializationAsBinary() = default;

    explicit ForSerializationAsBinary(int number)
            : number_(number) {}

    std::stringstream toBinaryStream() {
        std::stringstream out(std::ios::binary);
        out.write((const char *) &number_, sizeof(int));
        return out;
    }

    static void fromBinaryStream(ForSerializationAsBinary &obj, std::stringstream &os) {
        int n;
        os.read((char *) &n, sizeof(int));
        std::cout << "n: " << n << std::endl;
        obj.number_ = n;
    }

    int number_;
};
```